# What does that mean in c? char *array[]= { "**", "**", "**" };

Tags: c

In some code that I read, there was an initializing statement like this

```
char *array[]= { "something1", "something2", "something3" };
```

What does this mean, and what does that pointer actually point to?
How is that allocated in memory, and how can I access every element and every character of an element in that array ?

--- Edited --- 
and please what is the difference in this example between
char array[3];
and
char *array[3];
--- Edited ---

Comment: Think of it as a 2D array of characters or better yet, an array of strings

Comment: @user814628 This is one dimension array, not two dimensions. Try to `printf("%d\n", sizeof(array[0]));`. It will prints 4, pointer. Imagine it like it was: `AddressType array[]= { 0xXXXXXXXX, 0xXXXXXXXX, 0xXXXXXXXX };`

Comment: @Sp. Its how you interpret it, I know its an array of char* but for easier understanding OP can think of it as 2D array such that in his given example, `array[0][0] == 's'` holds true. So Although technically it might not be a 2D array, it can pretty much emulate like one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what that means ?

It's initializing an array of strings (`char *`) with three values (three pointers to null-terminating strings)

> and what that pointer points to ?

It should point to the first element in the `char*` array

> how is that allocated in memory ?

It will allocate enough memory to store the three strings followed by null-terminators, as well as the three pointers to those strings:

```
array --> pointer to three sequential memory addresses

array[0] --> something1{\0}
array[1] --> something2{\0}
array[2] --> something3{\0}
```

Note that the strings may not necessarily be in sequential memory

> and how can I access every element

if by "element" you mean the string, you can loop though the pointers:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    char* element = array[i];
}
```

> and every character of an element in that array

well, you could access the chars using array syntax (`element[i]`) but I would recommend using the [C string functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling) for safety (so you don't have to worry about accessing memory outside the range of the string)

Comment: tyvm , that was relly useful :)

Answer (score 6):

This is a way to initialize an array at the same time that you create it.

This code

```
char *array[]= { "a", "b", "c" };
```

will have the same result as this code.

```
char *array[3];

array[0] = "a";
array[1] = "b";
array[2] = "c";
```

Here is a good source for more information.

http://www.iu.hio.no/~mark/CTutorial/CTutorial.html#Strings

EDIT:

`char array[3];` is an array of 3 `char`.
`char *array[3];` is an array of 3 pointers to `char`.

Comment: okay, tyvm
but what is the difference between
char arr[3];
and 
char *arr[3]; ?

Comment: char array[3]; is an array of 3 char. char *array[3]; is an array of 3 pointers to char. (quoting the edit above)

Answer (score 4):

`char *` in C is a string.

`array` is the name of the variable being declared.

`[]` indicates that it is an array.

`{ "something1", "something2", "something3" }` is initializing the contents of the array.

Accessing elements is done like so:

`array[0]` gives the 1st element - "something1".

`array[1]` gives the 2nd element - "something2".

etc.

**Note:**

As was pointed out in the comments, `char *` isn't technically a string.

It's a pointer to a `char`. You can visualize a string in memory like so:

```
<-------------------------->
..134|135|136|137|138|139|..
<-------------------------->
  'H'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|'\0'
<-------------------------->
```

This block of memory (locations 134-139) is holding the string of characters.

For example:

`array[0]` actually returns a pointer to the first character in "something1".

You use the fact that the characters are sequentially in memory to access the rest of the string in various ways:

```
/* ch points to the 's' */
char* ch = array[0];

/* ch2 points to the 'e' */
char* ch2 = ch + 3;

/* ch3 == 'e' */
char ch3 = *ch2;

/* ch4 == 'e' */
char ch4 = *(ch + 3);

/* ch5 == 'e' */
char ch5 = ch[3];
```

Comment: `char *` is a pointer to `char`. A string is what it can point to, but not necessarily does or will.

Comment: so please again what is the difference between 
char a[3]; and char * a[3]; ?

Comment: `char a[3];` is making an array of three `char`s. `char * a[3];` is making an array of three `char*`s. `char*` means "pointer to a char"

Answer (score 3):

This defines a array of char pointers (aka. "c strings").

For accessing the content you could do:

```
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(char*); i++) {
    printf("%s", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I'm sorry, I forgot the division by `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: using `sizeof(array)/sizeof(char*)` might look funny at first, but is really great for C arrays as you do not need to hardcode the length of it. Since `sizeof` is determined at compile time it is just as fast as  using a constant here.

Answer (score 1):

It declares `array` as an array of 3 pointers to `char`, with its 3 elements initialized to pointers to the respective strings. The memory is allocated for the array itself (3 pointers) and for the strings. The strings memory is allocated statically. The array's memory is allocated either statically (if the declaration is outside of all functions) or dynamically (typically, on the execution stack of the CPU) if the declaration is inside a function.